# Firebug shows code other than what I wrote

Tags: jquery, html

Firebug displays code in browser that differs from the code that I wrote.

`<a href="#" class="info">Przejdź dalej</a>`

First set of code is what I wrote

Second code is what Firebug's interpretation of my code is.

```
<div class="oferta_option">
    <a class="oferta" href="silownia.php"> 
        <span class="text_oferta">Siłownia 
            <span class="italic_olymp">OLYMP</span>
        </span>
        <span class="view view-first">
            <img src="images/image_02.jpg" alt="img" />
            <span class="mask">
                <!-- <h2>Title</h2>  -->
                <p class="info_about">
                    Tutaj możesz znaleźć informacje o strefach rozmieszczenia sprzętu, zdjęcia sprzętu oraz cennik siłowni.
                </p>
                <a class="info" href="#">Przejdź dalej</a> 
            </span>             
        </span> 
    </a>
</div>
```

Firebug.

```
    <div class="oferta_option">
    <a class="oferta" href="silownia.php"> 
        <span class="text_oferta">Siłownia 
            <span class="italic_olymp">OLYMP</span>
        </span>
        <span class="view view-first">
            <img src="images/image_02.jpg" alt="img">
            <span class="mask">
                <!-- <h2>Title</h2>  -->
                <p class="info_about">
                    Tutaj możesz znaleźć informacje o strefach rozmieszczenia sprzętu, zdjęcia sprzętu oraz cennik siłowni.
                </p>
            </span>
        </span>
    </a>

    <a class="info" href="#">Przejdź dalej</a> 
</div>
```

Comment: I think down in the spans. Could be that firebug does not like that you place block elements (p) inside of inline elements (span).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11314668/what-elements-can-a-span-tag-contain-in-html5

Comment: okok but it isn't reason why is other code on www in firebug

Comment: Your HTML is (probably) invalid.  What Firebug is showing you is what it's *interpreting* it as.  Or rather, Firefox is interpreting your HTML code and Firebug is just showing what the browser is rendering.

Comment: Its not about firebug all browsers would render it in this way only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<a> tag can't be inside another <a> tag

<a id='f'>first
    <a id='s'>2nd
    </a>
</a>
```

rendered as

```
<a id="f">first
   </a>
<a id="s">2nd
   </a>
```

Answer (score 1):

"paragraph" is not allowed inside "span" tags according to the HTML specs.

Comment: firebug just reads the code displayed in the browser that is all it doesn't modify your code.

Comment: the browser can though.

Comment: i change p on span on other class and nothink all the time same effect

Comment: let me explain how this works...the browser compiles the html file and if the html protocol is broken it either fixes it (if it has the functionality) or continues past it. So to help you: get <p class="info_about">
                    Tutaj możesz znaleźć informacje o strefach rozmieszczenia sprzętu, zdjęcia sprzętu oraz cennik siłowni.
                </p> out of span