# How to position the text to top of the div in HTML?

Tags: html, css

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4aiG0.png)

Please refer to the attached screenshot. How to position the text "Arunraj" to the top of div(blue box). Now it automatically goes down.
Here is my code:

```
  <div>
    <span class="profile-pic"></span>
    <span>
      <div>
        <h3>Arunraj</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor simet</p>
      </div>
    </span>
  </div>
```

Comment: Div elements inside span elements is [not valid HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11314668/what-elements-can-a-span-tag-contain-in-html5).

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Comment: CSS: h3 { margin-top: 0; }

Comment: @Liren, please provide a properly-formatted answer below if you have one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vertical alignment of elements in a div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79461/vertical-alignment-of-elements-in-a-div)

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan sorry..I dont how to search with a screenshot and explain a search engine this particular situation. my bad

Comment: your `<h3>` tag closes as an `<h4>` tag (i.e. it DOESN'T close)...

Comment: The "Explain...any difficulties" part is also relevant... We expect people to have tried to fix the problem themselves before asking on SO.