# CSS 3: Transparent square-cut corner of (text) input element how to?

Tags: html, css, transparent

For a project I have to cut of the edge of (various) input elements as this is part of the website design. As the background may vary on different screen sizes the edges must be cut transparently that means that you must see the background of the below element where the edge is cut.

This is what I have to achieve:

[image: search field cut edge]

With rounded corners I would do the following:

```css
div {
  padding:30px;
  background-color:#c11;
}

input {
  display:block;
  border-top-right-radius:10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius:10px;
  background-color:#fff;
  border:0;
  height:30px;
  width:300px;
  padding:3px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
<input type="text" placeholder="Search ..." />
</div>
```

However I do not know how to do this square-cut. Do you know a way?

Comment: What browsers are you going to support?

Comment: Its o.k. if only the newest version of chrome, firefox and edge are supported.

Comment: The usual approach of using borders to create “css triangles” (research keyword) should work here, but there’s also a couple of other possible ways (background images, SVG masks, clippath, ...)

Comment: The answer of [Rakesh Soni](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44545087/1336174) is supported by most browsers and works in many older versions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easiest way is to add a div on each end and edit their borders. This way your search... placeholder isn't over the line, and you can add a button before then ending span to be a search icon.

```css
.back {
  padding:30px;
  background-color:#c11;
}
.bottom-corner, input, .top-corner, .icon{
  display:inline-block;
  padding:3px 10px;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
.icon{
  background-color:#fff;
  padding-top:10px;
  height:23px;
}
.bottom-corner, .top-corner{
  height: 20px;
}
.bottom-corner{
    border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid #fff;
    margin-right: -4px;
}
.top-corner{
  margin-left:-4px;
  border-top: 10px solid transparent;
  border-left: 10px solid #fff;
}
input {
  background-color:#fff;
  border:0;
  height:30px;
  width:300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="back">
<div class="bottom-corner"></div>
<input type="text" placeholder="Search ..." /><div class="icon">S</div>
<div class="top-corner"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @PaigeMeinke - it's actually a nice solution. You can replace the elements you've used with pseudo elements.

Answer (score 5):

You can use clip-path if your target browsers support it. The path can be defined using percentages, so it'll fit any screen size. However, Edge is not supported yet.

It's easier to create the path using [Clippy](http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/).

```css
div {
  padding: 30px;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #c11, blue);
}

input {
  display: block;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(calc(100% - 15px) 0, 100% 15px, 100% 100%, 15px 100%, 0 calc(100% - 15px), 0 0);
  clip-path: polygon(calc(100% - 15px) 0, 100% 15px, 100% 100%, 15px 100%, 0 calc(100% - 15px), 0 0);
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 0;
  height: 30px;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 3px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search ..." />
</div>
```

Comment: It is not working on mozilla @53.0.3 (64-bit) on mac

Comment: 54 is the 1st to support it

Comment: Interesting. Browser support is awful though! In the case of OP question, I think he's looking for something a bit simpler, maybe?

Comment: This is a nice solution unfortunatly the Browser support is still very poor.

Comment: Browser support is a major downside. However, it will work on every background.

Comment: Yes I hope in some months this is supported more widely. The big advantage is that for this solution it is not necessary to change the HTML which is always a drawback.

Answer (score 3):

A better way is to use borders

> It will support every browser.

See https://jsfiddle.net/kndx9od8/

```css
div.outer {
  padding: 30px;
  background-color: #c11;
}

div.con:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-bottom: 13px solid #c11;
  border-right: 14px solid transparent;
}

div.con:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-top: 13px solid #c11;
  border-left: 14px solid transparent;
}

div.con {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

input {
  display: block;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 0;
  height: 30px;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 3px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="con">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search ..." />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just a suggestion: maybe use a div instead of a span? Because some browsers do not allow non-inline elements (input is an inline-block) inside spans ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11314668/what-elements-can-a-span-tag-contain-in-html5)) They'll probably render it alright, but just for the sake of valid HTML.

Comment: Yes you are right but don't you  think `display: inline-block;` to span will do the work

Comment: It would work, yes, but the semantics would be wrong. It would be like putting a div inside a h1. It works, but it is not valid.

Comment: @DouwedeHaan Updated the answer, Thanks

Comment: Hum actually the corners are not transparent: If you apply `background:linear-gradient(to right, #1e5799 0%,#2989d8 50%,#207cca 51%,#7db9e8 100%);` it does not work anymore.

Comment: @DouwedeHaan inline-block is a CSS thing. It's perfectly (HTML5) valid to put an input into a span as well as a label for example. div and span have the same semantics: none. Then visually you'll probably have to set the CSS display property to anything else than the default for a span (inline-block, flex, etc)

Comment: @FelipeAls You're right. I read through some documentation again and confused the input with a div. A div is not allowed inside a span, but an input element is. (the w3c validator also returns errors if you put a div inside a span)

Comment: @Blackbam if  there is different background then you have to change the border color of the `div.con:after` `div.con:before` See https://jsfiddle.net/kndx9od8/2/

Comment: @RakeshSoni Sure but if a gradient or a picture is used as background  the corner is visible and not transparent

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option, using `transform: skew()` and pseudo elements

It works on all backgrounds, has a simple and easy to change code and is quite dynamic too, when it comes to different `input` width's/height's.

```css
div {
  padding:30px;
  background-color:#c11;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, darkred, #c11);
}
input {
  display:block;
  background-color:#fff;
  border:0;
  height:30px;
  width:300px;
  padding:3px 0px;
  outline: none;
}

div:nth-child(2) input {
  width: 400px;
  height:40px;
  font-size: 25px;
}

/* cut corners */
span {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
span::before,
span::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; top: 0;
  width: 15px; bottom: 0;
  background-color: white;
  transform: skewY(45deg);
  transform-origin: right top;
}
span::after {
  left: auto; right: 0; 
  transform-origin: left top;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search ..." />
  </span>
</div>

<div>
  <span>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search ..." />
  </span>
</div>
```